# GetOpt::Long module in perl for default values

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am writing a perl script which takes values as command line arguments and puts that in the assigned variables and executes query to a database.

```
GetOptions("version=s"      => \$ver,
       "product=s"      => \$prod) 
or die ("Error in input variables\n");
```

The query part of the script is as follows:

```
my $sql = qq|select count(*) from software_build where sw_version like ? and finished > '$date' and product like ?|;
my $sth = $dts->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($ver, $prod) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

What changes should I make that if the user do not include command line arguments than it should execute this query:

```
my $sql = qq|select count(*) from software_build where finished > '$date'|;
my $sth = $dts->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;
```

I need to execute this query by deafault if no command line arguments given. Thank you.

Comment: Use a hash for the option values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this following line and it works

```
if ($ver eq ""){
my $sql = qq|select count(*) from software_build where finished < '$date'|;
my $sth = $dts->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
my $count = $sth->fetchrow_array();
print $count;
}
else{
my $sql = qq|select count(*) from software_build where sw_version like ? and finished > '$date' and product like ?|;
my $sth = $dts->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($version, $product) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $count = $sth->fetchrow_array();
print $count;
}
```